# phpunit fails on laragon on windows 10

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laragon

I am developing project with laragon on windows 10 , i have installed phpunit 6.2 via composer. when i run phpunit command to run test in laravel project the following error occured

```
Warning: is_dir() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, object given in C:\Users\ddw14\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\BaseTestRunner.php on line 56

Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite could not be converted to string in C:\Users\ddw14\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Runner\StandardTestSuiteLoader.php on line 32
```

what could be the problem ?

Comment: Could you show the lines of code mentioned in the warning and the error descriptions above?

Comment: I have the same error on a standard laravel installation on ubuntu server

Comment: I had this same issue because my phpunit version was 5.7. After update to 6.2 everything went fine.